# DXA-2.2 java could not able to load entity from custom module

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

We are currently having application in dxa-2.2 java and we are trying to separate out common code out of it as separate dxa module.

It is not getting registered on viewEntryMap

here is a initializer code

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example.dxa.modules.test")
public class TestInitializer {

    @RegisteredViewModels({
            @RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "Test", modelClass = Test.class),
            @RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "Test", modelClass = RegionModelImpl.class)
    })
    @Component
    @ModuleInfo(name = "Test module", areaName = "Test", description = "Test module")
    public static class TestModuleInitializer extends AbstractModuleInitializer {
        @Override
        protected String getAreaName() {
            return "Test";
        }
    }
}
```

when I am trying to debug, I can not find this on

```
final RegisteredViewModels views = getClass().getAnnotation(RegisteredViewModels.class);
```

of class **AbstractModuleInitializer**

could you please suggest how to load this module into another dxa webapp which is having different module

Answer (score 1):

Issue was fixed when I changed the namespace to **com.sdl.dxa.modules** from **com.example.dxa.modules.test** in the module.

now able to load entities from custom module as well.

Comment: Interesting, it should not be needed to use the `com.sdl.dxa.modules` package name for custom Modules, but it's good to know that this is a way to make it work.

Comment: yes. In java it's expected